# UIWebView isn't loading

Tags: xcode4, uiwebview

I'm trying to use a UIWebView for the first time but I can't seem to make it load a page. The screen just remains blank.

I have a UIWebView in my storyboard. My `controller.h`:

```
@interface fishcoViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
```

My `controller.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Shouldn't the code in `controller.m` run when the view loads, which should make the webpage load? Instead I'm just seeing a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot - `[self.webView loadRequest:request];` This is what actually loads your url into the webView & it starts fetching from the net.

Comment: Sorry! I missed to add that line. It's actually there.

Comment: then it should work, did you link your webview declaration to the object in IB?

Comment: Ah ha! I had to drag the webView connector thingy to the controller. Thanks!